# Why function files in package are not recognized?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a package `common.geometry` with 2 files: `calculateAngle` and `normalizeAngle`. These files contain a single function, respectively:

```
package common.geometry {
import Graphics.Hexagon;

public function calculateAngle(hex1:Hexagon, hex2:Hexagon):Number {
    var diffY:Number = hex2.center.y - hex1.center.y;
    var diffX:Number = hex2.center.x - hex1.center.x;
    var radians:Number = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);

    return normalizeAngle(radians * 180 / Math.PI);
}
}
```

and...

```
package common.geometry {

public function normalizeAngle(angle:Number):Number {
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle += 360;
    }

    if (angle > 360) {
        angle = angle % 360;
    }

    return angle;
}
}
```

**Edit**
In *other* source files where I import `common.geometry.*` and I call `calculateAngle` the source compiles. But where `normalizeAngle` is called, I get a compiler error: *Call to a possibly undefined method normalizeAngle*.

I have tried explicitly importing `common.geometry.normalizeAngle` but this doesn't seem to work. What do I need to do so I can group global functions in packages?

Comment: you know! its not possible getting errors! if you have calling calculateAngle with no problem, and calculateAngle has a same location as normalizeAngle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the reference to the `Hexagon` class. It was causing a circular reference I believe. Since it is the `center` property of the Hexagon, I changed the parameters to take `Point` objects instead and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

no problem for me with this:

```
import common.geometry.calculateAngle;
calculateAngle();
```

as normalizeAngle and calculateAngle located in same location, and we only calling calculateAngle from out of the package, no need for importing normalizeAngle

**Edit**

I modified the original functions for clarity, removed arguments and replace bodies with simple `trace` commands.
`normalizeAngle` was called from  `calculateAngle` body correctly

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile, because it's not passing anything to the mandatory parameters of the function.

Comment: @null Yes, but its a snippet.just removed arguments by self to test it faster and only use a simple `trace` inside normalizeAngle and call it by calculateAngle as above just to check that its fine and works

Comment: I'm still not sure how this answers my question.

Comment: @IAbstract it just breaks your question,

Comment: @payamsbr: in source files other than `calculateAngle` and `import common.geometry.*` is called. I updated my question.